# C++ Eigen Is there a move constructor of Eigen::Vector3d class and how to call it?

Tags: c++, eigen, move-constructor

I suppose the Vector3d class of Eigen have the move constructor, so when I construct an
object, my code is listed as below:

```
struct Node{
    Node(std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d>&& set_means):means(std::move(set_means)){
    }
    std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d> means;
}; 
int main(){
    std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d> vec;
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
        vec.push_back(Eigen::Vector3d(i,i,i));
    }
    Node test_node(std::move(vec));
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure the move constructor of Node can successfully call the move constructor of Eigen::Vector3d.

On the other hand, what's the correct answer when I want to copy a vector of Eigen::Vector3d?

Comment: I'm not sure whether I get your question right, but wouldn't [`std::vector::emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) instead of `push_back` be an option here?

Comment: ... and you need to `std::move` the `Eigen::Vector3d` into the constructor...

Comment: did you check documentation? By doing the move you are actually on the safe side, because if it cannot be moved then it will be copied, thats how moving works for non-moveable types

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `Node test_node(std::move (vec));` works though

Comment: sorry guys. I make a mistake and the code is ```Node test_node(std::move (vec));```

Comment: This is better: `Node(std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d> set_means) : means(std::move(set_means)) {}`

Comment: `Eigen::Vector3d` stores its entries by value, so you will not save anything by having a specialized move-constructor (you could save something for `Eigen::Matrix<SomeVeryComplicatedScalarType, 3, 1>`). But `std::vector<T>` should have a move constructor also if `T` is an Eigen type.